# NameError: name 'httplib' is not defined

Tags: python, httplib

I get the following error on Python 2.6.x, how should I fix this?

```
  except (httplib.IncompleteRead), e:
NameError: name 'httplib' is not defined
```

Comment: Do you have `import httplib` somewhere before that statement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Import Module on file

```
import httplib
```

Comment: Also if this is Python 3, you should change the code to `except (urllib.IncompleteRead) as:` - the httplib portion is now all wrapped into `url lib`. So also add `import urllib` if you don't have it there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Import the module at the top of the file.